# Date-fns Unexpected results when adding months

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I am using date-fns for the first time in my project. I need to give user the ability to add a month to current date. I'm wondering how is this supposed to work with different length months?

I tried different months with 30 and 31 days and I cannot make sense of it.
If I add a month to July 1, 2022 I get July 31, 2022 (I would expect Aug 1st) but if I add a month to July 7 I get Aug, 7, 2022.

Also, I added a month to Feb, 15 2023 and the result I got is Mar, 14 2023 (was expecting March 15). Then when I add a month to Feb 1, 2023 I get Mar 1, 2023 which is good.

Here is my code:

```
export const addMonth(date, numOfMonths) {
  return addMonths(Date.parse(date), numOfMonths)
  // date is a date string
}
```

Appreciate if someone can advise.
Thanks

Comment: show us some examples of what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you havn't given any examples of what you have done its impossible to tell you where you have gone wrong a quick example using the date you say don't work

```
{
    const start = new Date(2022, 6, 1);
    const end = addMonths(start, 1);
    console.log(`start ${start} add 1 months= ${end}`);
}
{
    const start = new Date(2023, 1, 15);
    const end = addMonths(start, 1);
    console.log(`start ${start} add 1 months= ${end}`);
}
{
    const start = new Date(2023, 1, 1);
    const end = addMonths(start, 1);
    console.log(`start ${start} add 1 months= ${end}`);
}
```

shows

```
start Fri Jul 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) add 1 months= Mon Aug 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
start Wed Feb 15 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) add 1 months= Wed Mar 15 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
start Wed Feb 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) add 1 months= Wed Mar 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

so all working as expected

Comment: Sorry I thought, all I'm doing is using addMonths for date-fns so no need to add code. But guess it matters what date format I'm providing. So I have added code to my question

Comment: Hmm so looking at my code why would I get a different result?

Comment: May be its the the way you are using new Date. I get a date string from the api. So how can I convert to still have this result? Does it have to be provided in this format Date(2022, 6, 1) ?

Comment: date parse can struggle especially with localized date formats so make sure you use ISO 8601,also  try outputting your parsed date before you do the addmonths to check that it has the expected value

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Comment: Trying to make sense of this:
Note: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

Parsing of date strings is strongly discouraged? Guess that is what Im doing?

Comment: Date parse returns the number milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, new Date() returns the same number but inside a date wrapper that provides several functions to interpreting the number, that is what they mean by equivalent, but for example a date string of 02/03/2022, In UK that is 2nd Mar, in USA its 3rd Feb, parse doesn't take a format or culture so can't tell what format the date is in so will make its best guess, which doesn't always work

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will change my code to use the date constructor like you showed in the code. T